# Events from Email || Automatic Event Recognition

Tags: marketing-cloud, outlook

Use-case: Say I am sending an invite email from SFMC, with details about a new Product launch event.
I would like to pop up a event details like [here](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/b57ee228-6173-41c2-af3c-b6d6a2871ab6)

Upon researching on this feature, I got to know this feature auto detects email content and is currently supported in specific counties and types of events.
**Outlook official doc:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/automatically-add-events-from-your-email-to-your-calendar-32e5cf0c-3e65-4870-9ff9-df3683d3fc97

 **Supported senders:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/supported-senders-for-events-from-email-in-outlook-2c447af8-9e6c-481b-85df-e6d95325d6fd

**My Question:** Does anyone know which all domains is supported. Will it work if I send email from any domain from SFMC.

Comment: It is likely based on the sender's domain, the format and structure of the email. And implementation logic to an event that is automatically created in Outlook is probably determined by Outlook's own code and not the sender.